# Converting marks into grade into R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a very simple problem. Let's suppose, I have given marks of 100 students like this:

```
set.seed(1234)
Marks <- rnorm(100, 55, 10)

z <- runif(100)
Gender <- ifelse(z < 0.5, "M", "F")

#Creating Data frame
Df <- data.frame(SNo = 1:100, Marks, Gender)
head(Df)
```

Now, I need to provide grade to the students, but the grading criteria is different for Male and female. The grading criteria is:

[image: Grade Criteria]

I manage to solve this problem, but I did not find my method very appealing. I tried like this:

```
#1 Method
Grade = ifelse(Df$Gender == "M", cut(Df$Marks, breaks = c(0, 35, 45, 55, 101), labels = FALSE), 
                        cut(Df$Marks, breaks = c(0, 40, 50, 60, 101), labels = FALSE)) 
Grade <- as.character(factor(Grade, labels = LETTERS[4:1]))

#2. Method
Gradef <- function(x, cp = c(35, 45, 55)) {
  ifelse(x < cp[1], "D", ifelse(x < cp[2], "C", ifelse(x < cp[3], "B", "A")))
}

Grade2 <- ifelse(Df$Gender == "M", Gradef(Df$Marks), Gradef(Df$Marks, c(40, 50, 60)))
sum(Grade == Grade2)  #both method give same grade

Df$Grade <- Grade
```

Can someone please suggest me better method to solve the same problem? I do not want to use any external package in R.

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with method 1 specifically?

Comment: Both the methods give exact output. I want more efficient method. I think, the same problem can be solved with less line of coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your definition of efficient being less lines of code, I think this is what your are looking for, using your method 1, we just eliminate the need for the second bit:

```
Grade = ifelse(Df$Gender == "M", as.vector(cut(Df$Marks, breaks = c(0, 34, 45, 56, 101), labels = c("D", "C", "B", "A"))), 
           as.vector(cut(Df$Marks, breaks = c(0, 39, 50, 61, 101), labels = c("D", "C", "B", "A"))))

> head(Grade)
[1] "C" "B" "A" "D" "B" "A"
```

So one line of code needed.

Note: You could make the code more flexible, by replacing each piece in the code, for example,

```
labs <- c("D", "C", "B", "A")
```

And placing the labs variable in the code, this way you can now just change one bit of your code at the top, and then reuse your functions for different grading systems etc...

Code used:

```
set.seed(1234)
Marks <- rnorm(100, 55, 10)
z <- runif(100)
Gender <- ifelse(z < 0.5, "M", "F")
Df <- data.frame(SNo = 1:100, Marks, Gender)
```

Comment: Thanks @Hector. What is the logic of using as.vector ?

Comment: Hi, this is to convert the output of the cut function; into a nicer form, if you create some dummy data, and run cut with and without it, you will see :)

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist = list(F = c(35, 45, 55), M = c(40, 50, 60))
grades = c("D", "C", "B", "A")
Df$Grade = grades[1 + sapply(1:NROW(Df), function(i)
    findInterval(Df$Marks[i], mylist[[Df$Gender[i]]]))]
head(Df, 10)
#   SNo    Marks Gender Grade
#1    1 42.92934      F     C
#2    2 57.77429      F     A
#3    3 65.84441      M     A
#4    4 31.54302      F     D
#5    5 59.29125      F     A
#6    6 60.06056      F     A
#7    7 49.25260      M     C
#8    8 49.53368      M     C
#9    9 49.35548      M     C
#10  10 46.09962      F     B
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Cut` with label is the trick I would go for, something very similar @hector-haffenden above. This one is more step by step though.

```
set.seed(1234)
#Marks <- rnorm(100, 55, 10)

Marks <- 1:100  #for verification 


z <- runif(100)
Gender <- ifelse(z < 0.5, "M", "F")

#Creating Data frame
Df <- data.frame(SNo = 1:100, Marks, Gender)
head(Df)

cutsF<- cut(Df$Marks,breaks = c(0,35,45,55,100),labels = c('D','C','B','A') , right=F )
cutsM<- cut(Df$Marks,breaks = c(0,40,50,60,100),labels = c('D','C','B','A') , right=F )

Df$Grades= ifelse(Df$Gender=='F' , as.character(cutsF)  ,as.character(cutsM ) )

# For sake of Verification : 
Df$CutsF=cutsF
Df$cutsM= cutsM

head(Df ,20)
```

Edit : I have edited the code and replaced `include.lowest` with `right=False`. This closes the groups on the left and satisfies the less than 35 condition . However, this will not work for 55/60 . You might need to use 54, and 59 instead.

Comment: @hector-haffenden yeah. though I was not aware of your answer :-)  BTW , the less than 35 and more than 55 will pose an issue as well

Comment: Thank you :) missed that bit

Comment: @R.S. Thanks a lot. It is also very intuitive.